# C# Get dictionary key by value where value is of struct type

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, timer, key

please tell me is this possible to do and how to get this.

```
In C# I have a struct like:

public struct FrmData{
int num;
int x;
Timer t;
}
```

I use than dictionary where value is that structure.

```
public Dictionary<int, FrmData> dictionary;
```

when my Timer t elapsed, he raises event

```
public void eventHandlerTick(object sender, EventArgs e){
switch(key){case 1:break;}
}
```

my question is: can I somehow to get key of my dictionary from this timer which is raised this event ?!
thank you

Comment: `object sender` should be the Timer.  You can use the Timer itself as the key within the dictionary `Dictionary<Timer, FrmData>`, and so be able to get your form data via `dictionary[sender as Timer]`

Comment: If you're using a `struct` you shouldn't have a mutable struct, although in this case you shouldn't be using a `struct` at all, since your value doesn't conceptually represent a single value.

Comment: I can't use Timer as key and must be a struct as value because this struct is example. My real structure have much more data and Timer must be one of them. I'm new in C# and currently dont know another way to solve it. And I need this fast. But thank you.

Comment: @DraženkaLadišić The fact that you're actual type has a lot more data makes it all the more appropriate for that type to be a class, and not a `struct`.

Comment: probably, but as I said, I'm totally new to this and structure is the first thing that came to me. but thank you for advice. next time I will be using class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it would be to loop through the key value pairs, checking the value of each pair to see if it matches your timer.

Something like:

```
Timer t = sender as Timer;
foreach(var kvp in dictionary){ // Could also do KeyValuePair<int, FrmData> instead of var
    if(kvp.Value.Timer == t)
    {
         int key = kvp.Key
         // Do something with the key
    }
}

public struct FrmData
{
    int num;
    int x;
    Timer t;

    public Timer Timer
    {
        get { return t; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

My original response presumed your dictionary structure was set in stone.  If not, Will's comment will be the better option as it will enable you to more efficiently reference the structure.

Comment: Can you write litlle more detail of this code, dont understand completely. I'm new in C# and dont know how to write kvp.Value ?!.....

Comment: Sorry the code was meant to be a quick sample, so I didn't review it too carefully.  The foreach would actually be foreach(var kvp in dictionary).

Comment: Ok, now i'm getting error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands mystruct and System.Windows.Forms.Timer"  :(

Comment: sorry, I forget to write kvp.Value.timer

Comment: Sorry, kvp.Value provides access to  the structure, so you will need to drill down one step further to the timer.  To do this, you'll need to edit your structure to provide access  to the timer either by providing a property or making your Timer t public.  I'll update with an example.

Comment: This works!!!! Thank you, really really thank you, because now I can work further. I'm all new in this and google didn't help, great !